# Rails 5: Abstracting actions out of controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry, abstraction, ruby-on-rails-5.1

RoR 5.1.4.  My application is backed by MongoDB *via* Mongoid, and many of the models have similar handling.  I'm trying to make it as data-driven as possible, which means querying `Mongoid` for the models and Rails for the routes, neither of which can be done comfortably in initialisers because of eager loading and routes not yet having been set up.  The schema information (controller/model relationships, model fields, *etc.*, are stored in a singleton location, and making *that* happen and be accessible from class and instance environments has been a PITA.  However, that's background.

Most of the controllers support two upload actions, one *via* form file specification and one *via* request content body.  I'm using `webupload` and `upload` actions for these respectively, and since they're always handled the same (differences are determined by examining the aforementioned schema info), I want to abstract those two action methods, and their related before/after/.. relationship definitions, into a separate module.

A controller concern won't do it OOTB because the callbacks (*e.g.*, `:before_action` and friends) aren't declared in the inheritance, and I can't figure out what module I'd need to `include` in the concern in order to get them.

Helpers are out because they've been deprecated from controller inclusion (you need to take extra steps to get them), and they're primarily for views anyway.

So what is the pattern for writing/placing/including modules specifically for controllers, models, and tests?  That have the proper inheritance of methods for those functions?  (*E.g.*, `:before_action` for controllers, `:validates` for models, and so on.)

RoR is a wealthy hoard of features and hooks, but I'm finding it bloody hard to apply abstraction and DRY patterns to it simply because it **is** so rich.

Thanks for any help or pointers!

[EDIT] Someone suggested that I include some code.  So here in an abbreviated excerpt of my attempt to do this with a controller concern.

```
module UploadAssistant

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  #
  # Code to execute when something does a `include ControllerAssistant`.
  #
  included do
    #
    # Make the application's local storage module more easily
    # accessible, too.
    #
    unless (self.const_defined?('LocalStore'))
      self.const_set('LocalStore', ::PerceptSys::LocalStore)
    end

    def set_title_uploading
      title.base        = 'Uploading records'
      title.add(model_info.friendly)
    end                         # def set_base_title

    #+
    # Supply these routes to the controllers so they needn't define
    # them.
    #

    #
    # GET /<model>/upload(.:format)
    #
    def webupload
    end                         # def webupload

    #
    # POST /<model>/upload(.:format)
    #
    def upload
      title.add('Results')
      @uploads          = {
        :success                => {},
        :failure                => {},
      }
      errors            = 0
      @upload_records.each do |record|
        #
        # Stuff happens here.
        #
      end
      successes         = @uploads[:success].count
      failures          = @uploads[:failure].count
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          render(:upload,
                 :status   => :ok,
                 :template => 'application/upload.html')
        }
        format.json {
          render(:json     => @uploads)
        }
      end
    end

    def upload_file_params
      if (params[:file])
        params.require(:file).require(:upload)
        colname         = model_info.collection
        file_id         = params[:file][:upload]
        #
        # Get the file contents.
        #
      end
      @upload_records   = params.delete(model_info.collection.to_sym)
    end                         # def upload_file_params

    def upload_params
      @upload_records   = params.require(model_info.collection.to_sym)
    end                         # def upload_params

    def set_file_upload
      file_id           = params.require(:file).require(:upload)
      #
      # Read/decompress the file.
      #
      data              = JSON.parse(data)
      params[model_info.collection] = data[model_info.collection]
    end                         # def set_file_upload

  end                           # included do

  #+
  # Insert here any class methods we want added to our including class
  # or module.
  #
  class_methods do

    #
    # Stuff relating specifically to bulk uploading.
    #
    before_action(:set_title_uploading,
                  :only => [
                    :upload,
                    :webupload,
                  ])
    before_action(:set_file_upload,
                  :only => [
                    :upload,
                  ])
    before_action(:upload_params,
                  :only => [
                    :upload,
                  ])

  end                           # class_methods do

end                             # module ControllerAssistant

# Local Variables:
# mode: ruby
# eval: (fci-mode t)
# End:
```

Comment: The reason you're hitting the wall is that you´re really stepping outside the box of how rails is designed to work. Rails is built to work with a determinate route collection - while you can pry it apart and shoehorn your own design into there you´re really just losing what makes Rails productive. 

I would instead focus on making some generic CRUD resource type base controllers and drying shared behaviors into concerns.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way 'Rails is designed to work' is a pretty vague thing, and I'm *trying* to DRY shared behaviours into concerns -- but the concerns don't inherit the same modules as the controllers, and I can't figure out which ones I need.  And I sure don't want to have to repeat myself all over the place.  By using data-driven mechanisms, adding a new model and appropriate routes means editing one file and generating a new controller (and any unique view templates).

Comment: Well the first thing is when you are declaring instance methods - don't do it in `included do ... end`. That results in the methods being declared in the context of the class. You want them instead just in the body of the module so that the class refers to the module methods. This might seem minor but will drive you mad when looking at the stacktrace.

Comment: Just use `included do ... end` to perform actions in the class context like for example adding callbacks or using `attr_accessor` for example. `class_methods` should just be used to declare class methods (duh). I would recommend you read the docs for [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and maybe read up on how the module mixin pattern in ruby works.

Comment: You can use controller callbacks in a concern, just put `before_action :whatever` in the `included` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have completly misunderstood pretty much everything about `ActiveSupport::Concern` and how module mixins work.

Lets start by using composition to seperate concerns. For example:

```
module LocalStorage
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class_methods do
    # use a memoized helper instead of a constant
    # as its easier to stub for testing
    def local_storage
      @local_storage ||= ::PerceptSys::LocalStore
    end
  end
end
```

This makes sense to extract to a separate concern since its a reusable behaviour.

We can then compose an `Uploadable` concern:

```
module Uploadable
  # we compose modules by extending
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  extend LocalStorage 

  # put instance methods in the module body

  # GET /<model>/upload(.:format)
  def webupload
      # ...
  end

        #
  # POST /<model>/upload(.:format)
  #
  def upload
    # ...

  end

  # don't abuse use a callback for this - just use a straight 
  # method that returns a value and preferably does not have side effects
  def upload_params
    # ...
  end

  # ...

  # use "included" to hook in the class definition
  # self here is the singleton class instance
  # so this is where you put callbacks, attr_accessor etc
  # which would normally go in the class defintion
  included do
    before_action(:set_title_uploading,
              :only => [
                :upload,
                :webupload,
              ])
    before_action(:set_file_upload,
              :only => [
                :upload,
              ])
  end

  # just use class_methods for actual class_methods!
  class_methods do
     # for example to derive the name of a model from the controller name
     def resource_class_name
       controller_name.singularize
     end

     def resource_class
       @resource_class ||= resource_class_name.classify.constantize
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.  It is also an explanation I haven't been able to find anywhere else about how concerns work. I wouldn't say that I've misunderstood about mixins in general, but more about the way Rails has, erm, built upon the concept.  **Nowhere** have I found that the controller callbacks were available within the `included` block, so extra thanks for that.